# React Native - How to enable debugging Styles / UI inspector?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, debugging, inspector

I wish to debug my React Native UI. I looked through the documentation here

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools

It suggests using the following commands

```
npm install -g react-devtools
```

Then run

```
react-devtools
```

I did that, now it asks to copy the script tag before `React` is loaded in. React-Native doesn't have a `/public` folder like CRA (Create React App) does or an `index.html` file, where do I even put that script?

I used expo CLI to initialize my app

[image]

Comment: reload your app, react-devtools will automatically connect to it

Comment: That worked, I have the tools loaded in and can see the state on each component. But, when I use `toggle Inspector`, I can't see properties like `padding:5` on those elements, there's no modal popup similar to the docs. 

Examlpe image https://imgur.com/uxpdRjC

Comment: what modal popup ?

Comment: In the official docs, when you inspect an element, a modal pop up shows the bottom indicating the style properties associated with what your highlighting. https://i.imgur.com/p2WZsB9.png

Comment: it's not shown when react-devtools is connected, only when you turn off react-devtools

Comment: from the docs: However, when react-devtools is running, Inspector will enter a special collapsed mode, and instead use the DevTools as primary UI